# Running multiple queries off of a PHP page using mysqli::multi_query; queries work when executed separately but not together

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on a mock-bookstore website for an assignment where I must run queries off of a MySQL database I have and use PHP to construct webpages off of the information from the database.

One of the pages where all of the books are listed as well as links to filter genres is giving me issues. I have 2 stored procedures on my server that my PHP code uses to construct this page. Here is the relevant code:

```php
<?php
/*
username, password, and server name declarations up here
*/

$sqlConnection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 'volga_db');

// Check connection
if ($sqlConnection->connect_error)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $sqlConnection->connect_error);
}

$query = "call getAllBooks();";     // Stored procedure to get a list of all books and information relating to them
$query .= "call getAllGenres();";   // Stored procedure to get a list of all genres and their IDs

if ($sqlConnection->multi_query($query))
{
    $bookResultSet = $sqlConnection->store_result();

    while ($sqlConnection->more_results())
    {
        $sqlConnection->next_result();
        $genreResultSet = $sqlConnection->store_result();
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Error executing queries: " . $sqlConnection->error;
}
?>
```

Of note here is: if I comment out all code relating to `multi_query` and call either of the stored procedures all by themselves, the query functions as expected and I can visually see this when I open the page on my web browser. Additionally, I don't get the "Error executing queries" at all on my webpage, suggesting that the value returned by `multi_query` is `true`

I have tried writing the code in a couple different forms as seen below:

```php
$bookResultSet = $sqlConnection->query("call getAllBooks()");
$genreResultSet = $sqlConnection->query("call getAllGenres()");
```

```php
$query = "call getAllBooks();";
$query .= "call getAllGenres();";

$combinedResultSet = $sqlConnection->multi_query($query);

$bookResultSet = $sqlConnection->store_result();
$genreResultSet = $sqlConnection->next_result();
```

...and the large snippet above, however no matter how I write the code, I always get the same error: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on bool in C:\...\shop.php:73 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\...\shop.php on line 73`

I have also tried reversing the `$bookResultSet` and `$genreResultSet` as well, and interestingly enough when this happens the inverse occurs, where `$genreResultSet` displays properly and `$bookResultSet` throws an error when trying to call `fetch_assoc()`

All in all, I've done a fair amount of researching and tried many different solutions I've found on the internet, but haven't been able to find anything that gave me at least a different error message.

Comment: It was my understanding based on the research I've done that it was necessary to do this because initially, I did try running them separately but ran into the same error that I detailed in my post

Comment: Why are you trying to use `multi_query` at all? This is an extremely difficult and unnecessary function. Just use prepared statements and execute each with a new prepared statement.

Comment: You need to call `next_result` for each stored procedure, so you need 4 of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I discovered that stored procedures return a multiset. I remedied the issue by clearing out each subsequent result set as shown:

```php
$bookResultSet = $sqlConnection->query("call getAllBooks()");
$sqlConnection->next_result();
$genreResultSet = $sqlConnection->query("call getAllGenres()");
$sqlConnection->next_result();
```